# How to Train scikit-neuralnetwork on images

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm trying to train a classifier to recognise different shapes on tags in my images (circles, rectangles and blank - examples down below) and thought that scikit-neuralnetwork might be able to help as I haven't had much success with an SVM. I found the documentation on their site, but am not sure about the format the data I use to train the network should be in.

```
from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Convolution, Layer

nn = Classifier(
    layers=[
        Convolution("Rectifier", channels=8, kernel_shape=(3,3)),
        Layer("Softmax")],
    learning_rate=0.02,
    n_iter=5)
nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

My grayscale images are 24*24 pixels, so can I have a NumPy array ("X_train") composed of these matrices? That way I don't have to flatten each image into a row that forms my training matrix and I lose all the shape information (which is what was happening when I trained my SVM, LDA, PCA, etc).

[image]

Comment: One of the best way to detect and recognize shapes are the convolutional neural networks. I point you to one of **many** tutorial on deep learning out there using the [nolearn package](https://pythonhosted.org/nolearn/lasagne.html): http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to flatten a data. Just feed an array of matrices. In your case `X_train.shape` would be (NUM_OF_EXAMPLES, 24, 24). Take a look at [digits example](https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/blob/master/examples/plot_digits.py).

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried the example with my image data and with virtually no edits to the code I got a 75% correct prediction rate! Do you have any advice for where I could go to find out more about the layers settings in the classifier? I feel that if I play around with those settings I could get my accuracy into the 90s.

Comment: Setup correct NN topology with all hyperparameters is not a trivial task. Take a look to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02788v1.pdf) about how each hyperparameter effects to model performance.

Comment: Try to train a separate NN for each shape. You may get more accuracy. The more the training data, less error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use multidimensional representation for each sample in set, numpy allows it.

You can think about following example as about 4 images in training set each with size (2,3)

```
>>> np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(4,2,3)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

        [[ 6,  7,  8],
         [ 9, 10, 11]],

        [[12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]],

        [[18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23]]])
```